# The algebraic set $V$ is connected if and only if the coordinate ring $k[V]$ is not the direct sum of two nonzero ideals.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, ideals, zariski-topology

Let $V$ be an affine algebraic set in $\Bbb{A}^n$.  Then $V$ is connected in the Zariski topology on $V$ if and only if $k[V] = k[\Bbb{A}^n]/I(V)$ is not the direct some of two ideals.  I'm stuck trying to prove the $\Rightarrow$ direction.  By direct sum I assume they mean usual direct sum thinking of ideals as submodules, so I need to prove that $k[\Bbb{A}^n]/I(V) \neq J/I(V) \oplus K/I(V)$ for any two ideals $J,K$ in $k[\Bbb{A}^n]$ properly containing $I(V)$.  Unsure how to proceed.

Comment: By connected do you mean irreducible ? Look at $xy=0$.

Comment: Dear @Rene: no, by connected the OP means connected and his criterion is perfectly correct. Your example is connected: what shall we learn by looking at it ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Do you have a reference (book) for this definition ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus a subset is connected if it can't be written as the disjoint union of two proper open subsets in the induced topology on that subset.  In particular, affine algebraic varieties are connected in the Zariski topology induced on the algebraic set making up the variety.

Comment: @EnjoysMath So the union of two irreducible varieties is connected iff they have a point in common.

Comment: No rush on the answer, I want to study about $k[V]$ in my book some more and maybe find the answer there.

Comment: @EnjoysMath which text are you reading ?

Comment: Dummit & Foote @ReneSchipperus

Comment: @EnjoysMath Happy new year.

Comment: I think I got one direction.  Uses Zariski continuity of morphisms of algebraic sets.  Not sure if that's true though.  Looking into it...

Comment: @ReneSchipperus  THANKS!  U2

Comment: @EnjoysMath I can give a solution if you are ready for it.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus ready when you are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is an old question, I would like to point out that the question is not correct. It requires the field $k$ to be algebraically closed. Here is the proof of => part:

Assume $k[V] = J/\mathcal{I}(V)\oplus K /\mathcal{I}(V)$, where $\mathcal{I}(V)$ is defined as maximal ideal in $k[A^n]$ such that all element of it vanishes on algebraic set $V$. Also $J$ and $K$ are two ideals in $k[A^n]$. Therefore, due to direct summation, we have $J \cap I = \mathcal{I}(V)$. Then $\mathcal{Z}(J \cap I) = \mathcal{Z}(J) \cup \mathcal{Z}(K) = \mathcal{Z}(\mathcal{I}(V))=V$, where $\mathcal{Z}(C)$ denotes the common zeros of polynomial in set $C$. Since $J/\mathcal{I}(V)$ and $K/\mathcal{I}(V)$ are both nonzero, $\mathcal{Z}(J)$ and $\mathcal{Z}(K)$ are not empty. Thus, it contradicts the hypothesis that $V$ is connected.

For the <= part (assume that $k$ is algebraically closed):

Suppose that $V = V_1 \cup V_2$ with $V_1 \cap V_2= \phi$ ($V_i$, $i=1,2$, is not empty). Since $k$ is algebraically closed, $V_i = \mathcal{Z}(I_i)$, $i=1,2$, for some radical ideal in $k[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$ by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. Thus $V = \mathcal{Z}(I_1 \cap I_2)$. Thus $\mathcal{I}(V) =I_1 \cap I_2$. Furthermore, $V_1 \cap V_2 = \phi$ implies that $\mathcal{Z}(I_1 + I_2) = \phi$. By Nulsterlensatz again, we have $I_1 + I_2 = k[A^n]$. Now, applying Chinese Remainder Theorem, we have $k[V] = I_1/\mathcal{I}(V)\oplus I_2/\mathcal{I}(V)$. It reaches a contradiction.

The counterexample for <= part. Let $\mathbb{R}$ be a real set. Consider $\mathbb{R}[A^2]$. Let $V_1 = \mathcal{Z}(x^2+y)$ and $V_2=\mathcal{Z}(y-1)$. Then $V_1 \cap V_2 = \phi$. So $V=V_1 \cup V_2$ is not connected. $\mathcal{I}(V) = ((x^2+y)(y-1))$. Then $\mathbb{R}[V]$ can't be written as a direct sum. To see this, if the direct sum exists, it must have a non-trivial idempotent element in $\mathbb{R}[V]$. But it is easy to see such an idempotent doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, it depends on the setup - the formerly accepted answer is perfectly good for the scheme-theoretic context! It's only the "classical" setting where $\Bbb A^n$ is $k^n$ plus blah where you'd need to add the algebraically-closed assumption. That's something the asker should probably take care of, no?

Comment: I come to this question while I am studying Dummit’book. This question is one of the exercises in the book. However, in his errata, the author changes the exercise to require algebraical closure assumption and asks to construct an counter example. I googled many times and didn’t get a satisfying answer. Today, I finally figure things out. So I think it may be worthwhile sharing here.

Comment: @HankScorpio I am not there (understanding scheme) yet. You can consider it is my study note :).

Answer (score 1):

Assume $k[V]=J/I\oplus K/I$ where $I=I(V)$.
Then there are $f\in J$ and $g \in K$ such that 
$$1+I=(f+I)+(g+I)$$ or in other words 
$$1=f(x)+g(x)$$ for $x\in V$.
Further $J\cap K \subseteq I$ since the sum is direct. And so $fg \in  J\cap K \subseteq I$ and thus 
$$f(x)g(x)=0$$ for $x\in V$.
Now we show the open sets 
$$D(f)=\{x | f(x) \neq 0\}$$ and 
$$D(g)=\{x | g(x) \neq 0\}$$ disconnect $V$.
$$D(f)\cap D(g)\cap V= D(fg)\cap V =\emptyset$$
To see $V \subseteq D(f)\cup D(g)$ let $x\in V$ then $f(x)+g(x)=1$ so either $f(x)\neq 0$ or $g(x)\neq 0$.